# How does Firefox or any other HTML5 browser validate emails addresses?

Tags: firefox, email, regex

Specifically I am talking about the regex that they have on the backend. I have downloaded the Firefox source code, and I have been `grep`ing through it, but it is so huge that I always get too many results to sift through.

How do they this or where do I look in the source code for it?

Comment: Are you after the firefox implementation specifically, or the one specified in the [HTML5 specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#valid-e-mail-address) ?  They are probably the same.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786058/find-the-regex-used-by-html5-forms-for-validation